# Are these how's meaning 'how well'?

Tags: conjunctions, exclamations

It’s not easy how I have to read clauses starting with *how*. I’m going to start this question with a case from [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/how) –– “*He was impressed at **how well** she could read!* (A)”.

Though Longman says *how* is used to emphasizing with adjective or adverb, Random House says *how* intensifies not only adjective or adverb but also the whole sentence without them –– “*How it rain!, How I envy you!*”

So far it’s not that hard to follow. But when *how*-clause becomes a content clause, I’m confusing this **exclamative content clause** –– “*She told me how very aggressive he had been*. (CGEL,p991)” and cases in which *how* is read as [conjunction that; the fact that; the way that](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/how) –– “..referring to *how* Capone was eventually charged with tax evasion rather than criminal activity”. This aforesaid that-usage is, I guess, based on “[in dependent question and exclamations](https://archive.org/stream/newenglishdict05murrmiss#page/n449/mode/1up)”.

**[Q i]** 
Now, what I want to ask is can the Langman’s case (A) be rewritten without meaning change into “He was impressed at **how** she could read”. The examples below put me up to this question.

> 1 Then she changed her desk into a pig and back again. They were all
>   very impressed and couldn't wait to get started, but soon realized
>   they weren't going to be changing the furni-ture into animals for a
>   long time. After taking a lot of complicated notes, they were each
>   given a match and started trying to turn it into a needle. By the end
>   of the lesson, only Hermione Granger had made any difference to her
>   match; Professor McGonagall showed the class **how** it had gone all
>   silver and pointy and gave Hermione a rare smile.
>
> 2 Malfoy had been even more unpleasant than usual since the Quidditch
>   match. Disgusted that the Slytherins had lost, he had tried to get
>   everyone laughing at **how** a wide-mouthed tree frog would be
>   replacing Harry as Seeker next. Then he'd realized that nobody found
>   this funny, because they were all so impressed at the way Harry had
>   managed to stay on his bucking broomstick. So Malfoy, jealous and
>   angry, had gone back to taunting Harry about having no proper family.
>
> – Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, p.134; 195

**[Q ii]**
Now, vice versa, can these two how’s can be rewritten into [how well or how good](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/how)?

Comment: This question is based on a misconception. *How* doesn't really carry any special implications of *well* or *good*. The basic meaning is *in what way/manner* (and that's *all* it means in OP's examples #1 and #2). Sometimes it means *in an **extreme** manner*, as in [How we laughed to see such fun!](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22how+we+laughed+to+see+such+fun%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) I'd also say Longmans example is relatively uncommon compared to *He was impressed **by** how well she could read!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, “How we laughed to see such fun!” -> When this is possible –– “how (loudly) we laughed”, “how (well) it had gone all silver and pointy” isn’t ? That’s what your language goes, would be the answer for my aspect. But what about WordRefernece.com’s [#3](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/how) - how good; how well? Is this different from my question?

Comment: I think wordreference.com's #3 is stretching things a bit. The examples are really just "special cases" of sense #1, where the speaker takes it for granted the reply will be some level of "goodness". But you could ask, for example, *"How was your visit to the dentist?"* or something else where the expected reply might well be some level of "badness". The implied nuance in such usages is highly context-specific (and usually *obvious*). But it's not part of the meaning of the word ***how*** in and of itself - it's just part of the context in which the word is used.

Comment: Here, "how" can be changed into "how well" or "how loudly". Depending on the sentence used, how can have different (or none, rarely) adverbs assigned to it to colour up the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"How" describes the way in which something is carried out. To say "How well" is to state the condition of wellness of the action. So, if someone did something *very* well, then that is showing the condition of the wellness of the action. How Well can not be used in place of every how, only some.

TL;DR: 
 Q1: No, you cannot remove "well" from that sentence without changing the meaning, otherwise it'll be saying that Langman was impressed by the way she read. I don't see why someone should be impressed by a specific way of reading.

Q2: No, these cannot be rewritten into "how well".